# Tools for Load testing for rubycas server

Tags: load-testing, rubycas

We have implemented SSO using [rubycas server](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server), we want to do load test on this and we are looking for open source tools which are the good for load testing.

Comment: Must it be open source or are free commercial solutions also acceptable?

Comment: @CMerrill free commercial solutions are also fine

Answer (score -1):

There is pretty good set of open source tools for the load tests. You can check some of them [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php).

Is not easy to choose proper tool. All depends on the specific case what kind of staff you would like to test. If you would like to do simple throughput testing or just measure the responsiveness of you system, I would recommend one of these:

- [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
- [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/)

but if you would like to test some more advance "user stories" then I will suggest:

- [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Trample](https://github.com/jumph4x/trample)